# Dont want to reload Texture from Server in onResume in AndEngine Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, andengine

Please have a look at the following piece of code

```
ITexture mTexture = new BitmapTexture(
                            mEngine.getTextureManager(),
                            new IInputStreamOpener() {
                                @Override
                                public InputStream open()
                                        throws IOException {


                                    URL url = new URL(
                                            "http://tenlogix.com/cupcakemania/"+ImageName+".png");

                                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                                            .openConnection();
                                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                                    connection.connect();
                                    InputStream input = connection
                                            .getInputStream();
                                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                                            input);
                                    return in;
                                }
                            },TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
```

Through this code I am making a sprite from an image placed on the Server.The problem is that when onPaused is called AndEngine unloads all resources and then in onResume the engine reloads the resources. Because this texture is made from an image placed on web it takes time to reload. Is there any way to avoid this? I dont want it to reload again and I want if its loaded once it should not be unloaded until I want. Please note that I am doing this task as Async Task in background. I will be happy to know your solutions to my problem.
Thanks

Comment: Load and cache your image inside internal/external storage during the game loading (splash screen)? Network is not available anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Don't release this resource in onPause.  If only onPause is called, then your app is still essentially in the foreground, but e.g. the screen may have been switched off or there may be a pop-up dialog partially obscuring it.  You want your UI to remain intact, and you don't want to incur long delays in onResume.

Better to release it in onStop or onDestroy/onDestroyResources.   onStop will be called if another app takes the foreground, but your app hasn't completely exited.  onDestroy will be called when your app exits completely.  I would suggest loading the image in onCreateResources, and unloading it in onDestroyResources.

As another commenter has suggested, you should also consider caching the image locally to allow your app to start without an internet connection.  I guess you must have a reason for not packaging the image with your APK, but you might want to consider at least providing a placeholder image in the APK and then downloading/caching updated images as required.  If you don't want to cache the image, then you can display your placeholder quickly and load and replace with your remote image asynchronously.

Comment: Saving it to device or in APK is of no use to me. I have a solution which I have implemented, instead of making texture and sprite from that image I am not making drawable bitmap from image on a server my problem is now solved. Thanks for your help and support